# How to select a second div following any dom element?

Tags: css

how to give a float left attribute to the second div following the h3 ?

```
<div class="view-content">
  <h3>
  <div>
  <h3>
  <div>
  <h3>
  <div>
  <div>   this one !
  <h3>
 <div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you fix your closing tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain [adjacent sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors):

```css
h3 + div + div {
  float: left;
  background: yellow;
}

h3 + div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="view-content">
  <h3></h3>
  <div>not this</div>
  <h3></h3>
  <div>nor this</div>
  <h3></h3>
  <div>or this</div>
  <div>but this one !</div>
  <h3></h3>
  <div>not this</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanx. but could u tell me how can i make that yellow div only  floating left of the previous line ?

Comment: You could add `h3 + div {display: inline-block}`.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
 .view-content div:nth-of-type(2) //Mistaken
 {
   float:left;
 }
```

it ll solve your problem. Thanks for pointing me the errors

Comment: the div is not inside the h3